# Why does this relation fail symmetry and transitivity properties?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations, equivalence-relations

The question states, let $S$ be the set of all humans.
Define $a ∼ b$ iff $a$ is a full-brother
of $b$. 
Symmetry: Since $a$ shares both parents with $b$, then $b$ shares both parents with $a$. Would this be false because $b$ is not defined as a male, so $b$ is instead the full sister of $a$? 
Transitivity: Since $a$ shares both parents with $b$, and $b$ shares both parents with $c$, then a shares both parents with $c$. What does the $c$ mean in this context? Is it simply another person introduced?

Comment: $c$ is a variable for a third person.  Transitivity would hold if $a,b,c $ were required to be different people.  But it fails if $a $ and $c $ are the same person.

Comment: That makes more sense. It never defines a,b, and c as being distinct. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your title is inaccurate.  An equivalence relationship *can't* fail symmetric and  transitive properties, by definition, and this is *not* an equivalence relation *because* it does fail.

It fails reflexive because $a $~$a $ never happens.  No-one is their own brother.

It fails symmetry for exactly the reason you state. If Allen, a boy, and Betty, girl, have the same parents than Allen is a full brother to Betty, but Betty is not a full brother to Allen.

Update!

Transitivity fails.  If Allen is a full brother to Bob.  And Bob is a full brother to Allen then Allen is not a full brother to Allen.

Transitivity fails.

Comment: I have corrected it. Does it read correct now?

Comment: Yes.  it's a relation.  But it's not an *equivalence* relation.  It's not an equivalence relation *because* it fails.  BTW I don't know why your book says transitivity fails.

Comment: I understand. It is a book by my professor Alex McCallister, "A Transition to Advanced Mathematics: A Survey Course." I have spent several hours attempting to understand why transitivity fails, when it does not, unfortunately.

Comment: Got it!  If $a$ and $b $ are both boys then $a=b$ and $b=a$ but $a\ne a$.

Answer (score 4):

I am a full brother of my sister, but my sister is not a full brother of me.  So this relation is not symmetric.

EDIT: Transitivity fails: see fleablood's comment.

Comment: ... and yes, in this case $c$ is just a third person introduced.

Comment: Since a is a full brother of b and b is a full brother of c means that both a and b are males, so c can be a sister to a and b. Even in that case, a is the brother of c. However, the back of my book says that all properties fail. I do not know if this is a type or not. Thank you both!

Comment: " Transitivity is true though. If  a is a full brother of  b and  b is a full brother of c , then is a full brother of a".  Not if a and c are the same person!  Transitivity fails.

Comment: Oops: you're right!  Editing.

Answer (score 2):

For a relation to be equvalence relation you also need *reflexivity* that is 
$$
a\sim a, \qquad \forall a \in S.
$$ 
which would mean that $a$ is a full brother of himself which is absurd.

Reflecting on your other questions if you define $\sim$ to be brothership then you definitely run into trouble with different sexes. So in case of $a$ and $b$ has different sex it is not holding up.

For the question about transitivity you would read, "a is a full brother of b" and "b is a full brother of c". I would say that this holds up.

I hope I could help

EDIT:

According to the comments below not even transitivity is fullfilled

Comment: This helps. Thank you! I am trying to figure out why the back of the book states that all properties fail for this relation. Perhaps it is a type. I have seen a few along my journey through it.

Comment: " For the question about transitivity you would read, "a is a full brother of b" and "b is a full brother of c". I would say that this holds up" it fails if a and c are the same person.

Comment: @fleablood but if $a$ and $b$ are the same person then this is not transitivity rather symmetry, or am I missing something?

Comment: If A and B are different people but full brothers then A~B and B~A.  Transitivity would imply that A~A.  Which is false.  I didn't say it failed if A and B were the same person; I said it fails if A and C were the same person.

Comment: I understand but I still consider transitivity having to deal with $3$ different elements of the set

Comment: "I still consider transitivity having to deal with 3 different elements of the set".  It doesn't.  In fact, a relation that is both symmetric and transitive would be required to be reflexive.

Comment: Hmm...true...thanks!